# Hide select tag when input is not empty

Tags: javascript, html

UPDATE: Thanks for the answers!
I can't seem to figure it out, even with the functions you guys posted. Here's the code I use. Also - I have jQuery on my site, but I didn't know you can do it with jQuery.

```
<form method="post" action="" name="items">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Link URL:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="item_url" size="25"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Link name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_name" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Site Name:</td>
                            <td id="site_id">
                                    <select name="item_site_id">
                                            <option value="<?php echo $sites["site_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $sites["site_name"]; ?></option>
                                    </select>
                            </td>                    
                    </tr> (the form contiunes, but only this part is relevant...)
```

Basically I want to make it so, that when the user enters anything into the "LINK URL" line (input name item_url), the SELECT tag (site_id) disappears.
Thanks again for helping me :)

EDIT2: RESOLVED, thanks for the help! 
One more question - How can I track the SELECT? I want to make it so, that item_url and item_name disappear if user changes the select. is that possible?

Comment: @ggreiner, Is this question tagged `jquery`?

Comment: @Gabe - Lighten up, it wouldn't be the first time a question has been mis-tagged.

Comment: No where does the OP refer to `jquery`. Seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when you want to have it happen, since you didn't specify I used the `onblur` `event`. You could use `onchange`, `onkeydown`, `onclick` etc the same way.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJbEB/) Example

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onblur="hideSelect(this);" />
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideSelect(txt){

    if(txt.value.length == 0){
        document.getElementById('mySelect').style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
       document.getElementById('mySelect').style.display = "inline";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Basic*** example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NDSE3/

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = function(){
    var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

    if(this.value == '')
        select.style.display = 'inline';
    else 
        select.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Why set an `inline` element to `display` as `block`?

Comment: @Gabe Just changed it. Though, there are many circumstances when you may want to do that ;) Especially to save `fluffy HTML markup`, but that's another topic...

Comment: Fair enough, but for sake of simplicity is why I bring it up.

Comment: @gabe Agreed, in all fairness I overlooked it and can't think of an instance where I've had to make an `input type="text"` field `display:block` :) - good catch...

Comment: No problem, you fixed it. Just wanted to see if there was a particular reason.

Answer (score -1):

If you're open to using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it's fairly easy.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/justrhysism/hnuHQ/

**The HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="myTextInput" />

<select id="mySelectBox">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$('#myTextInput').change(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
        $('#mySelectBox').show();
    } else {
        $('#mySelectBox').hide();
    }
});
```

Either put the script in jQuery's `$(document).ready()` handler, or simply load it after the HTML in the DOM.

*Note: This will hide the select box when the text box loses focus, not immediately. If you want to hide it immediately try using the keyUp() event handler.*

Comment: This question is not tagged `jquery`

Comment: I understand that, however not everyone is aware of jQuery and the advantages it provides. The question didn't state that he mustn't use jQuery.